# How to parse e.g. 2010-04-24T07:47:00.007+02:00 with Python strptime

Tags: python, date, strptime, rfc3339

Does anyone know how to parse the format as described in the title using Pythons strptime method?

I have something similar to this:

```
import datetime    
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(entry.published.text, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.Z')
```

I can't seem to figure out what kind of timeformat this is. By the way, I'm a newbie at the Python language (I'm used to C#).

UPDATE

This is how I changed the code based on the advise (answers) below:

```
from dateutil.parser import *
from datetime import *
date = parse(entry.published.text)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That date is in ISO 8601, or more specifically [RFC 3339](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601_usage), format.

Such dates can't be parsed with `strptime`.  There's a [Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue5207) that discusses this.

[`dateutil.parser.parse`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) can handle a wide variety of dates, including the one in your example.

If you're using an external module for XML or RSS parsing, there is probably a routine in there to parse that date.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good way to find the answer: using `strftime`, construct a format string that will emit what you see.  That string will, by definition, be the string needed to PARSE the time with `strptime`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parse RSS or Atom feeds then use [Universal Feed Parser](http://www.feedparser.org/). It supports [many date/time formats](http://www.feedparser.org/docs/date-parsing.html).

```
>>> import feedparser                 # parse feed
>>> d = feedparser.parse("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/3946689")
>>> t = d.entries[0].published_parsed # get date of the first entry as a time tuple
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(*t[:6])         # convert time tuple to datetime object
datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 15, 22, 46, 56)
```

Answer (score -1):

That's the standard XML datetime format, ISO 8601. If you're already using an XML library, most of them have datetime parsers built in. `xml.utils.iso8601` works reasonably well.

```
import xml.utils.iso8601
date = xml.utils.iso8601.parse(entry.published.text)
```

You can look at a bunch of other ways to deal with that here:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/WorkingWithTime

Comment: "an XML library". Which one? Do you mean PyXML?

Comment: Most XML libraries include convenience functions for parsing XML datetimes. PyXML happened to be the example I included.